# Java Self-referential generics with two types

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Let’s say we have an abstract class like this one:

```
abstract class Table<T extends Table<T, P>, P extends Menu<P>> { }
```

How to correctly declare its implementation?

```
public class TableImpl extends Table< **SOMETHING GOES HERE** > { }
```

I tried some variants and the only workaround I’ve found was to create additional classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractMenu extends Menu<AbstractMenu> { }
public abstract class AbstractTable extends Table<AbstractTable, AbstractMenu> { }
```

Then it’s possible to declare TableImpl like this:

```
public class TableImpl extends AbstractTable { }
```

**EDIT 1**

Based on Ingo's answer it now looks like this:

```
public class MenuAndTableTest {

    public abstract class Table<X extends Table<X>> {

        public abstract <M extends Menu> M getParent();

        public abstract X getThis();
    }

    public abstract class Menu<T extends Menu<T>> {

    }

    public class MenuImpl extends Menu<MenuImpl> {

    }

    public class TableImpl<M extends Menu> extends Table<TableImpl<M>> {

        M parent;

        public TableImpl(M parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        @Override
        public TableImpl getThis() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public M getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void Test() {
        // given
        MenuImpl menuImpl = new MenuImpl();
        // when
        TableImpl<MenuImpl> tableImpl = new TableImpl<>(menuImpl);
        // then
        assertEquals(tableImpl, tableImpl.getThis());
        assertEquals(menuImpl, tableImpl.getParent());
    }
}
```

But now some extra logic comes to Table implementations - not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: So you want a table of tables and menus which are menus of menus?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want.

Comment: @Boris Menu is some Page Object containing Table in it. Table should be able to return it's parent (Menu) in method like `P getParentPage() { return parentMenu; }`

Comment: @Isaiah The main idea - table of tables with its menu.

Comment: Please, please, please rethink your logic!

Comment: @Bubletan I want to be able to use method chaining when I work with Table and Menu implementations and keep base logic inside abstract classes. Also each Table implementation should keep link to its parent environment.

Comment: You can do it if you have it as `<P, T>` instead of `<T, P>`, I believe.

Comment: @Louis I tried several options but seems this not working. Can you provide some example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a table that can conatin a table that contains menus, why don't you declare it as

```
class Table<X>
```

and instantiate with

```
Table<Table<Menu>>
```